# Could the Kernel stack of a process be empty, when a process is swapped out to a disk?

Tags: kernel, swap

I am just curious to know whether the Kernel stack could be empty when a process is swapped out to a disk or not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: What is *a process is swapped out to a disk*?
**process** is never swapped out, **pages** are.

Also: Kernel stack of a process is always empty when the process is not in kernel state.